# Can anyone help me prove this real-analysis limit problem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ and $g$ be real-valued functions defined on $(a, \infty)$ and suppose that $\lim{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) =\infty$. Then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(g(x))=L$

Hi! Can anyone help me prove this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would you like a hint or a complete answer?

Comment: Hint: try using sequences $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ to restate your $\lim$ equations.

Comment: Also, nowhere in your problem have you used continuity. May want to consider renaming the question. It probably makes more sense to call it a real analysis limit problem.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of a limit (at infinity), for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $M_1\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $M_1<x$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, the function increases without bound as $x$ tends to infinity. This means that for every $M_2\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta$ such that $\delta<x$ implies $M_2<g(x)$.

If we take $M_2>M_1$, then there exists $\delta$ such that $\delta<x$ implies

\begin{align*}
|f(g(x))-L|<\epsilon
\end{align*}
and we're done.